# ImageDataGenerator keras - save_to_dir

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-processing

I cannot find how to identify classes after saving to directory. It saves images names with random numbers.

ex. "_1_1234.png"

```
ImageDataGenerator.flow(
    x,
    y,
    batch_size=32,
    shuffle=True,
    sample_weight=None,
    seed=None,
    save_to_dir= "path_to_dir",
    save_prefix="",
    save_format="png",
    subset=None,
)
```

Comment: thanks for the question, but the provided info is not enough to help solve your problem. please add additional details that would help us solve this problem.

Comment: The number after the first underscore in the image name corresponds to the index of the image. For example, if the filename is `"_123_4568.png"`, then its corresponding label would be `y[123]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of experimenting here is how you can do it.The code below will provide the original file names and associated labels.Labels are integer class indices corresponding to the classes. That is filenames[0] has the label labels[0] etc. The class_indices attribute is a dictionary that contains the mapping from class names to class indices. For example if you have 2 classes cats and dogs the dictionary will be {'cats': 0, 'dogs': 1}. Now it turns out if you run the image_data_generator with shuffle=False the generator saves the augmented files with random file names however the first digits before the second underscore seems to be the order in which the file was processed. So _0_random number was the first file processed. So its associated label in the code below would be labels[0] etc.So you can determine which class the saved images belonged to that way. Now you may want to train with shuffle=True. Now the generator shuffles the images, however the digits before the second underscore still represents the original image order. So if it is labelled _10_random number than this images label is label[10].

```
data_gen=ImageDataGenerator.flow(
    x,
    y,
    batch_size=32,
    shuffle=True,
    sample_weight=None,
    seed=None,
    save_to_dir= "path_to_dir",
    save_prefix="",
    save_format="png",
    subset=None,
file_names= data_gen.filenames
labels= data_gen.labels
label_dict=data_gen.class_indices
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding some key in the save_prefix. then it will pickup the image name with it.